# Geolocalização no emulador Android Studio

Tags: visual-studio, kotlin, geolocalização

Por que ele está trazendo localização EUA no emulador android studio? É possível fazer essa correção ?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vá na opção Expanded Controls, como na imagem:

[image: Expanded Controls]

Depois habilite a opção de GPS em *Enable GPS* e por fim clique no local do mapa que desejar e em seguida clique no botão <kbd>Set Location</kbd>, dessa forma irá definir o local que deseja:

[image: set location]

Para buscar um local especifico use o buscador acima do mapa:

[image: Busca localização mapa do emulador]

Em seguida de o zoom e clique no local (rua, área, etc) que desejar e faça o mesmo procedimento anterior clicando em <kbd>Set Location</kbd>.

Você pode salvar localizações especificas também usando o botão <kbd>SAVE POINT</kbd>, você poderá salvar várias localizações assim e a partir disso também poderá criar rotas para que o GPS no emulador simule que você está se movimentando.

Vá na aba routes, busque pela rua ou cidade que deseja e clique em qualquer local desejado do mapa, vai aparecer na parte de baixo um ícone redondo (como na imagem) para definir o destino:

[image: Criar rota]

Por fim você pode salvar essa rota ou pode definir a velocidade do movimento em *Playback Speed* e depois iniciar a simulação de navegação clicando em <kbd>Play Route</kbd> como na imagem:

[image: Iniciar rota]